# Problem to deploy Spring-Boot Application to Remote server with remote PostgreSQL Db

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have spring-boot app woth application-properties:

```
spring.jpa.database=postgresql
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

server.port=${PORT:8080}

spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.sql.init.platform=postgres
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://1**.1**.**.**6:****/dbname  # server address
spring.datasource.username=n******
spring.datasource.password=p********
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

and in my local computer i use:

```
scp -P 1111 D:\user-home\test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar user@111.111.11.111:/home/user
```

and then of course

```
java -jar test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

and I have

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:315) ~[postgresql-42.2.22.jar!/:42.2.22]
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51) ~[postgresql-42.2.22.jar!/:42.2.22]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223) ~[postgresql-42.2.22.jar!/:42.2.22]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465) ~[postgresql-42.2.22.jar!/:42.2.22]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264) ~[postgresql-42.2.22.jar!/:42.2.22]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar!/:5.4.32.Final]
```

My postres in pom:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.22</version>
        </dependency>
```

[PASTEBIN](https://pastebin.com/nNSeYjE1) Here is full console view with error. None of the solutions found work. Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like whichever server you are running the jar from is not able to access the database server on that port. You should check to make sure that the firewall on both sides is configured correctly (JAR server allows traffic out on the database port and the database server allows traffic in on the database port from the JAR server's IP address).

You can test the connectivity using telnet by running the command `telnet <database-ip> <port>` e.g. `telnet 123.123.123.123 9876` from the JAR server (assuming telnet is available). If it is able to establish a connection, then running the JAR should be able to run again and connect to the database.